# Save products in basket , when close activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mono

I have basket activity when I add products from list of products.

Code of adding attributes

```
add.Click += delegate {
        var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(CartActivity));
        intent.PutExtra ("title", (string)(firstitem ["post_title"]));
        intent.PutExtra ("price", (string)(firstitem ["price"] + " грн"));
        intent.PutExtra ("weight", (string)(firstitem ["weight"] + "г"));
        StartActivity (intent);
    };
```

Code of receiving attributes

```
productname.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("title");
    price.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("price");
    weight.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("weight");
```

I tried OnPause

```
namespace MurakamiKiev
{
[Activity(Label = "Murakami",  Icon = "@drawable/logo", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class CartActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
```

But when I run activity I have black screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save text when I close activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460924/save-text-when-i-close-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Did you call SetContentView() in OnCreate()?

like this

```
namespace MurakamiKiev
{
    [Activity(Label = "Murakami",  Icon = "@drawable/logo", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class CartActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.YourLayout);
        }
    }
}
```